# Text editing small program

Tags: c#, string

The program should return edit text, where you have to replace" - ", ": ", "; ", ", ", " " with "\t".

The problem here is the result

```
Input: Китай: 1405023000; 24.08.2020; 17.99%

Expected    Китай   1405023000  24.08.2020  17.99%

Myne        Китай:  1405023000; 24.08.2020; 17.99%
```

So for some reason, I believe he messing with the order of `stringSeparators` elements or what. I am interested in this moment

```
public static string ReplaceIncorrectSeparators(string text)
{
    string populationEdited = "";
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {" - ", ": ", "; ", ", ", " "};
    for (int i = 0; i < stringSeparators.Length; i++)
    {
        populationEdited = text.Replace(stringSeparators[i], "\t");
    }

    return populationEdited;
}
```

I've already solved the problem in another way but I want to solve it with separators.

Comment: What is "Китай" ? Please translate to English, as this is an Engish only sight.

Comment: @wohstad that isn't important. The program is editing punctuation marks only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that it doesn't store the result of `Replace` properly. This should do the trick:

```
public static string ReplaceIncorrectSeparators(string text)
{
    string populationEdited = text; // You need to start with the original
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {" - ", ": ", "; ", ", ", " "};
    for (int i = 0; i < stringSeparators.Length; i++)
    {
        // And here instead of text.Replace you do populationEdited.Replace
        populationEdited = populationEdited.Replace(stringSeparators[i], "\t");
    }

    return populationEdited;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Regex as an alternative. It would make your code shorter (an in my opinion more readable).

```
public static string ReplaceIncorrectSeparators(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@" - |: |; |, | ");
    return regex.Replace(text, "\t");
}
```